# How can i add to a list in python without creating it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, loops

I have the following django view for finding the average score of a questionnaire.

```
@login_required
def statistics(request, slug=False):
    qn = get_object_or_404(Questionnaire, slug=slug)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=qn).count()
    qs = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=qn)
    responses = Response.objects.filter(question__in=qs, user=request.user).count()
    if questions == 0 or responses == 0 or not questions <= responses:
        return render(request, "questionnaire/stats.html")
    out = {}
    for q in qs:
        response = Response.objects.filter(question=q, user=request.user).order_by("session_datetime").first()
        out[q.category] = {}
        time = response.session_datetime
        time_string = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        out[q.category][time_string] = []
        responses_in_time = Response.objects.filter(question=q, user=request.user, session_datetime__gte=time,
                                                    session_datetime__lt=time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24))
        for res in responses_in_time:
            out[q.category][time_string] += [res.value]
    print(out)
    for category in out.keys():
        print("outcat"+ str(out[category]))
        for time in out[category].keys():
            out[category][time] = sum(out[category][time])/len(out[category][time])
    print(out)
    return render(request, "questionnaire/stats.html", context={"questionnaire": qn, "stats_json": json.dumps(out)})
```

and i am wondering if there is a way to put together the dictionary with a time from the model/record in the loop without reseting it each time, if i try += without creating it first it complains but i do not know the initial time inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i dont know why i can only think of an answer just after ive posted but here is the working code. by looping through twice, once to create the dict and once to fill it i have solved this.

```
@login_required
def statistics(request, slug=False):
    qn = get_object_or_404(Questionnaire, slug=slug)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=qn).count()
    qs = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=qn)
    responses = Response.objects.filter(question__in=qs, user=request.user).count()
    if questions == 0 or responses == 0 or not questions <= responses:
        return render(request, "questionnaire/stats.html")
    out = {}
    response = Response.objects.filter(question=qs.first(), user=request.user).order_by("session_datetime").first()
    time = response.session_datetime
    time_string = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    for q in qs:
        out[q.category] = {}
        out[q.category][time_string] = []
    for q in qs:
        responses_in_time = Response.objects.filter(question=q, user=request.user, session_datetime__gte=time,
                                                    session_datetime__lt=time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24))
        for res in responses_in_time:
            out[q.category][time_string] += [res.value]
    print(out)
    for category in out.keys():
        print("outcat"+ str(out[category]))
        for time in out[category].keys():
            out[category][time] = sum(out[category][time])/len(out[category][time])
    print(out)
    return render(request, "questionnaire/stats.html", context={"questionnaire": qn, "stats_json": json.dumps(out)})
```